# EXC_BAD_ACCESS inside sha256_block_data_order when optimized and arm64

Tags: c++, ios, openssl, arm64

I'm using OpenSSL for encryption inside my iOS app, and when the library is compiled for arm64, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000105094000` on certain occasions. The memory address is on another continent from the allocations made for the app itself, which leads me to think there's a pointer issue somewhere, but I'm lost about how to go about tracking it down.

These are the top two items in the stack trace, both inside the OpenSSL library.

```
sha256_block_data_order + 108

SHA256_Update + 220
```

Underneath those is my code.

The crash only occurs when arm64 is in the OpenSSL library (libcrypto.a) and when optimizations are turned on, even at the lowest levels.

I'd be appreciative if anyone could point me in the right direction on tracking this down.

Comment: To be completely sure you're running on the device for this?

Comment: Happens on both simulator and device.

Comment: Well the simulator never runs that architecture.  arm64 will only run on a device that's arm64.  x86_64, sure.

If you're looking for something that crashes on a 5s + and your mac, it's likely some kind of bit width issue.